# Timeline de conteúdo com jcarousellite

Tags: jquery, carousel

Estou criando uma linha de tempo usando o jCarouselLite, porém está com um bug quando avanço para uma década nova. Por exemplo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Nas setas cinzas consigo navegar para outras datas, e nas coloridas pula para outra década.

O bug seria o seguinte: quando estou na década (por exemplo) de 80 e seleciono algum ano (exemplo: 1985), quando avançar para a próxima década, gostaria que ela iniciasse no ano de 1995 e não em 1990.

Se eu estiver em 1982 e avançar uma década, quero que comece em 1992 e não 1990.

Vou mostrar no exemplo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

E

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Segue uma parte do código meu código HTML:

```html
<div class="reconhecimento anos-80" id="ano-80">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2 class="oitenta">1980</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="oitenta">1981</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="oitenta">1982</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="oitenta">1983</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="oitenta">1984</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="oitenta">1985</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- reconhecimento -->

<div class="reconhecimento anos-90" id="ano-90">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2 class="noventa">1990</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="noventa">1991</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-80.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-80.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="noventa">1992</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="noventa">1993</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-80.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-80.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="noventa">1994</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-70.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-70.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>

    <li>
      <h2 class="noventa">1995</h2>
      <a id="foto" href="files/timeline-80.png">
        <img src="files/timeline-80.png" />
      </a>    
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- reconhecimento -->
```

JS:

```
$("#ano-80").jCarouselLite({
  btnNext: ".anos-proximo",
  btnPrev: ".anos-anterior",
  circular: true

});

$("#ano-80").jCarouselLite({
  btnNext: ".anos-proximo",
  btnPrev: ".anos-anterior",
  circular: true

});


$("#ano-70").jCarouselLite({
  btnNext: ".anos-proximo",
  btnPrev: ".anos-anterior",
  circular: true

});

$("#ano-90").jCarouselLite({
  btnNext: ".anos-proximo",
  btnPrev: ".anos-anterior",
  circular: true

});
```

Comment: @renan obrigada pelo retorno, confesso que não estou conseguindo passar o problema.

Eu tenho que "zerar" iniciar o carrousel, quando pular para outra década.

O que está acontecendo eh se eu estou na data 1985 e for pular para próxima década 90 o carousel carrega apartir da data de 1995, e não da data 1990. Como as imagens mostra.

Comment: Tentei editar a pergunta, se não tiver melhorado você pode [reverter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/116013/revisions) quando quiser. Eu entendi o que você quer fazer, mas não conheço o plugin para formular uma resposta.